# Avoid printing after executing command in console

Tags: ruby

I am opening very big YAML file. It takes a while. But after it opened it it is printing all its content - and it takes many times more time for it.

So how can I avoid printing result in Ruby console:

```
data = YAML.load_file( ... ) # some 1GB data file.
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script you're using, possibly with a pastebin like http://gist.github.com. Also, what version of ruby are you using (tell us what `ruby -v` says)?

Comment: Are you talking about the print output in irb? Set `conf.return_format = ""`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you are doing this in the console. I usually add just "; :ok" if I don't want to see the output.

```
data = YAML.load_file( ... ) ; :ok
```

Comment: I do the same but with `nil`.

Comment: Easy solution is easy, and doesn't muck up when you actually _want_ to see the return output like the `conf` option does.

Comment: With Pry (http://pry.github.com/), suppress output of the result simply by adding the semicolon.

Answer (score 14):

In [Pry](http://pry.github.com) you can suppress output just by adding the semicolon:

```
pry(main)> data = YAML.load_file( ... );
pry(main)>
```

Output suppression is explained in the wiki [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/User-Input#wiki-Suppress_output)