# Mute output of IRB for a specific class

Tags: ruby

Im working with a class, containing large instance arrays.

Whenever I initialize a class like this, e.g. `i = Image.new`, I get a lot of junk output from my arrays (`@r`, `@g`, `@b` - ~300k values each).

```
 class Image

   def initialize(width=640, height=480, brightness=64)
     @width, @height, @brightness = width, height, brightness
     self.load('usart.dat')
   end

   def load(file='usart.dat')
     self.reset
     f = IO.read(file, @height * @width * 2, 0)

     # Parsing the datafile, saving data in @r, @g, @b, @gray etc

     end

     return self
   end

   # ... More methods
 end
```

Question is, how can I either silence the output (all results are saved to a file, never viewed in the console) or make an initializer NOT inspect self. I want to return `self`, since I want to stack methods, e.g. `image.load('file').binary.grayscale.save(:bin)`.

Comment: Similar question (but with slightly different goal) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360616/avoid-printing-after-executing-command-in-console/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output you are seeing is the result of your object's `to_s` (or `inspect`). You can define/overwrite `to_s` (or `inspect`) for your classes to produce less output. E.g.

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo
irb(main):002:1>   def initialize
irb(main):003:2>     @a = @b = @c = @d = 42
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1>
irb(main):006:1*   def to_s
irb(main):007:2>     'a Foo object'
irb(main):008:2>   end
irb(main):009:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> h = Foo.new
=> a Foo object
irb(main):011:0>
```

Regarding `to_s`/`inspect`: irb calls `inspect` which normally just calls `to_s` (see [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect)). So, defining `to_s` should normally work. However, if there is an `inspect` not calling `to_s` in the class (or its ancestors), this `inspect` has to be overwritten.

Comment: However, I don't get the results you do. Overriding the to_s-functionality doesn't seem to have no effect: http://pastie.org/3051817

Comment: @AllanNørgaard: Please try defining `inspect`.

Answer (score 8):

A common workaround for this type of problem is to just add `; nil` in IRB, e.g. `i = Image.new ; nil`. This way the last evaluated expression is `nil` which will also be returned.

```
>> Foo.new 
=> #<Foo:0x00000000e3b9d0 @a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]>
>> Foo.new ; nil 
=> nil
```

Comment: I would rather make changes to the class, since I have to type that in the console every time. But interesting trick, I will have to remember that

Answer (score 5):

Disable irb echoing:

```
conf.echo = false
```

The gem [utility_belt](http://utilitybelt.rubyforge.org/) will give you commands `quiet` and `verbose` to disable/enable the output (and more).

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the return value of Foo.new to *not* return the new Foo object, you would never be able to assign the new Foo to any variable. If the only concern is occasionally scrolling the console view, use the ";nil" approach.

Comment: I didn't know that, but it makes perfectly sense. Thanks